# Android version and its kernel

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to port Android Lollipop to a board and as such require that a modified kernel be written (simple modifications, nothing to major).

However I just can't find information anywhere where it says the minimum required kernel version to build Android 5.0 or greater.

For instance I've already made the required adjustments for Linux 3.18 which also has a corresponding version Android kernel version.

If anyone can answer my question it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51651/which-android-runs-which-linux-kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any place that officially specifies minimal kernel version for particular Android version. From devices running Lollipop I personally know, my nexus 7 has the oldest kernel - 3.1. If you check `https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/tegra.git` git repository, there is for example `android-tegra3-grouper-3.1-lollipop-mr1` branch that is based on kernel 3.1 and seems to be for Lollipop. Most of the devices (also working on Lollipop) I work with run on kernel 3.4, and very few on 3.10.

I remember reading about some small features introduced in Lollipop that are only available if you have kernel 3.10 or newer but can't find details now. I'll update my answer if I find it again.

Comment: The Samsung Galaxy Nexus runs Lollipop on kernel 3.0. :P